# Converting AngularJS theme into normal HTML theme

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-material

I am about to develop a web application. I will use this theme- http://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/ for admin panel. I already installed it on my local machine following the instructions. But this is my first time of installing a html theme like this using command lines (npm, gem and gulp).

I also noticed that all the AngularJS admin panel theme are has to be installed in that way. I mean using npm and other commands. Installation is fine. When I run this command

```
gulp serve
```

It opens the browser and show the admin panel. But the problem is I do not understand the project structure.

[image]

Admin panel is working when I serve gulp. But what I want is I just want to access without serving gulp. I mean I want to move it to xampp. Then integrate with a framework(PHP). So for now when I access directly, it is not working. What I want is I just want to have simple project, something like this

```
/project
========
       /css
       /js
       /view
```

How can I build them into it? I mean using command lines. For now I have to serve gulp to access my project. To convert it manually, I checked the index.html and there are a lot of syntax commented I am not familiar with.

eg

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
```

How can I convert the Angular theme into simple project to send to server for deployment? Can it be done from command lines?

Now my project is under

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/material_dashboard/angular-material-dashboard
```

When I access this

```
 http://localhost/material_dashboard/angular-material-dashboard/src/
```

It shows nothing. Just white screen. No error in browser console as well.

When I access this

```
http://localhost/material_dashboard/angular-material-dashboard/.tmp/serve/
```

It is showing these errors.

[image]

All status code 404 returns.

How can I access the project without serving Gulp? From which url can I access?

Comment: you don't have to use the development server;  just copy the files from the output directory to the web server of your choice, no "conversion" necessary.  If you have tried to access the index.html from your web server and are getting an error message, post that error, otherwise it's not possible for others to know what you might have missed.

Comment: did you actually `build` the project?  try running `gulp build`, and then copying *that* output to your server.

Comment: Yes I built running that command. :(

Comment: If you want to make this theme to not be a single-page app that relies on Angular, this is not possible, because it depends on Angular Material.

Comment: why are you trying to access the `/src/` tree?  once the project is built, you should be just loading the index.html from the project root....

Comment: There is no index.html in the root.

Comment: Copy content of the **dist** folder to place from where you want to serve it. Then serve it over http / https protocol.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks so muchhhhhhh @KrzysztofSafjanowski . it is working now. Really appreciate it. Will u post the answer? I gonna upvote and green up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Development server

Angular applications are mix of JavaScript, HTML, CSS and every paths is relative to the root of application - index.html.

In this case copy contents of dist folder. Copy whole dist folder and deploy it.

Development server just tries to simulate real one production server. If it is working on development - that one that is executed over `gulp server` it should also works on production environment.

#### Production environment

It is time to go straight with application. There are only two major steps

- build it with `gulp build` (of course if you are using gulp and there is task like that)
- **copy content** of the builded directory to production environment (that steps is also called deployment)

#### CORS issue?

AngularJS application and the backend should be executed (should run) on the same protocol, domain and port address to avoid CORS policy rules.